# Wget page title

Tags: shell, wget

Is it possible to Wget a page's title from the command line?

input:

```
$ wget http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 <<code>>
```

output:

```
If it’s broke, fix it right   - Keeping it Real Estate. Home
```

Comment: You'd need to parse the html retrieved and extract the text contents of the html head title. And for the sake of sanity don't attempt to use regexes for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This script would give you what you need:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 \
  | sed -n -e 's!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p'
```

But there are lots of situations where it breaks, including if there is a `<title>...</title>` in the body of the page, or if the title is on more than one line.

This might be a little better:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 \
  | paste -s -d " "  \
  | sed -e 's!.*<head>\(.*\)</head>.*!\1!' \
  | sed -e 's!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!'
```

but it does not fit your case as your page contains the following head opening:

```
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
```

Again, this might be better:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 \
  | paste -s -d " "  \
  | sed -e 's!.*<head[^>]*>\(.*\)</head>.*!\1!' \
  | sed -e 's!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!'
```

but there is still ways to break it, including no head/title in the page.

Again, a better solution might be:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 \
  | paste -s -d " "  \
  | sed -n -e 's!.*<head[^>]*>\(.*\)</head>.*!\1!p' \
  | sed -n -e 's!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p'
```

but I am sure we can find a way to break it.  This is why a true xml parser is the right solution, but as your question is tagged `shell`, the above it the best I can come with.

The `paste` and the 2 `sed` can be merged in a single sed, but is less readable.  However, this version has the advantage of working on multi-line titles:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 \
  | sed -n -e 'H;${x;s!.*<head[^>]*>\(.*\)</head>.*!\1!;T;s!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p}'
```

**Update**:

As explain in the comments, the last sed above uses the `T` command which is a GNU extension.  If you do not have a compatible version, you can use:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 \
  | sed -n -e 'H;${x;s!.*<head[^>]*>\(.*\)</head>.*!\1!;tnext;b;:next;s!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p}'
```

**Update 2**:

As above still not working on Mac, try:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 \
  | sed -n -e 'H;${x;s!.*<head[^>]*>\(.*\)</head>.*!\1!;tnext};b;:next;s!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p'
```

and/or

```
cat << EOF > script
H
\$x
\$s!.*<head[^>]*>\(.*\)</head>.*!\1!
\$tnext
b
:next
s!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p
EOF
wget --quiet -O - http://bit.ly/rQyhG5 \
  | sed -n -f script
```

(Note the `\` before the `$` to avoid variable expansion.)

It seams that the `:next` does not like to be prefixed by a `$`, which could be a problem in some sed version.

Comment: Wow amazing! But I tried the last solution and got: `sed: 1: "H;${x;s!.*<head[^>]*>\( ...": invalid command code T` as an error.

Comment: `T` is a GNU extension to sed.  You are probably running the script on something else than Linux.  In this case, you can change `;T;` by `;tnext;b;:next;'.  I will update the answer.

Comment: another error: `sed: 2: "H;${x;s!.*<head[^>]*>\( ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)` Running OSX, but I brewed gnu-sed on this machine, so surprising.

Comment: Are you sure: it works fine for me on cygwin.  Maybe you are missing the last `}` at the end of the sed command.

Comment: Ran it on a different laptop, running OSX 10.7.3 (Lion), instead of OSX 10.6.9 (Snow Leopard).. Used ssed instead of sed and your edit still fails, jfgage, which I'm not too sure why?? Maybe it's a mac thing, or a win thing... Either way, if you use ssed over sed, the original version kicks ass. Solved!

Comment: Note that the opening `<title>` tag also might have attributes (if you don't believe me, check Google Play ;). So better use `<title[^>]*>` in that place as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following will pull whatever lynx thinks the title of the page is, saving you from all of the regex nonsense.  Assuming the page you are retrieving is standards compliant enough for lynx, this should not break.

```
lynx -dump example.com | sed '2q;d'
```